# How to use a function for multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a dragable box. You can see my codes in below:

```js
// To change the position of pop-up
function handle_mousedown(e){
    window.my_dragging  =  {};
    my_dragging.pageX0  =  e.pageX;
    my_dragging.pageY0  =  e.pageY;
    my_dragging.elem    =  $(".fast_login_form");
    my_dragging.offset0 =  $(this).offset();
    function handle_dragging(e){
        var left = my_dragging.offset0.left + (e.pageX - my_dragging.pageX0);
        var top = my_dragging.offset0.top + (e.pageY - my_dragging.pageY0);
        $(my_dragging.elem)
        .offset({top: top, left: left});
    }
    function handle_mouseup(e){
        $('body')
        .off('mousemove', handle_dragging)
        .off('mouseup', handle_mouseup);
    }
    $('body')
    .on('mouseup', handle_mouseup)
    .on('mousemove', handle_dragging);
}

 // make draggable 'fast login form'
 $(".fast_login_form_header").mousedown(handle_mousedown);
```

```css
.fast_login_form{
  border: 2px solid gray;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}

.fast_login_form_header{
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fast_login_form">
    <div class="fast_login_form_header"> click and hold and move </div>
</div>
```

The above code works as well, But it is just for one box according to this line:

```
my_dragging.elem  =  $(".fast_login_form");
```

Now I want to know, how can I implement that function for every box? Not just `.fast_login_form`? Actually I want to know how can I pass `$(".fast_login_form")` as a parameter to that function?

---

In other word, I want to create another box like this in the HTML:

```
<div class="another_fast_login_form">
    <div class="fast_login_form_header"> click and hold and move </div>
</div>
```

And I want to make it draggable too. I can write those code twice for both of them, but I want to know how can I use those codes for multiple boxes?

Comment: you can write it like this: `my_dragging.elem  =  $(".fast_login_form, .another, .andanother, #withID, div");` just separate selectors with commas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `$(this).closest('.fast_login_form')` instead of `$('.fast_login_form')`

```js
// To change the position of pop-up
function handle_mousedown(e){
    window.my_dragging  =  {};
    my_dragging.pageX0  =  e.pageX;
    my_dragging.pageY0  =  e.pageY;
    my_dragging.elem    =  $(this).closest('.fast_login_form');
    my_dragging.offset0 =  $(this).offset();
    function handle_dragging(e){
        var left = my_dragging.offset0.left + (e.pageX - my_dragging.pageX0);
        var top = my_dragging.offset0.top + (e.pageY - my_dragging.pageY0);
        $(my_dragging.elem)
        .offset({top: top, left: left});
    }
    function handle_mouseup(e){
        $('body')
        .off('mousemove', handle_dragging)
        .off('mouseup', handle_mouseup);
    }
    $('body')
    .on('mouseup', handle_mouseup)
    .on('mousemove', handle_dragging);
}

 // make draggable 'fast login form'
 $(".fast_login_form_header").mousedown(handle_mousedown);
```

```css
.fast_login_form{
  border: 2px solid gray;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}

.fast_login_form_header{
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fast_login_form">
    <div class="fast_login_form_header"> click and hold and move </div>
</div>

<div class="fast_login_form">
    <div class="fast_login_form_header"> click and hold and move </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The above is the simplest, fastest way to implement the functionality you need, but I would recommend using a different class to indicate something is draggable.  You could make both divs be `<div class="fast_login_form draggable">` and `<div class="another_fast_login_form draggable">` and then change the one line to `$(this).closest('.draggable');`.  You can then make the trigger line more generic with `$(".draggable .fast_login_form_header").mousedown(handle_mousedown);`

Comment: I see, ok tnx .. just for your last point, I have to say, I want **only** *header* part of `div` be draggable. So I don't need to write this line `$(".draggable").mousedown(handle_mousedown);`. Am I right?

Comment: @stack Yes, you are right.  I updated my comment after realizing I made that mistake.

Comment: Look .. This answer is great `:-)` I love you buddy `;-)` .. Because when I move one element and `show()` another element, they will not be linked

Answer (score 3):

Just use a selector which selects all draggable elements, for example give them a class `draggable` and select them with `$(".draggable")`. And instead of using a global variable (`window.my_dragging`), use a local variable `var my_dragging`, so it will be unique to each element.

Comment: This is the more reliable solution.  Mine is a quick fix, but a dedicated class and local variable is more ideal.

Answer (score 1):

why not just make a new class "draggable", add that to any element that you want draggable also switch your selector to use

```
my_dragging.elem  =  $(".draggable");
```